# Does Stim support the Mølmer–Sørensen gate?

Tags: stim, ion-trap-quantum-computing

The [Mølmer–Sørensen gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8lmer%E2%80%93S%C3%B8rensen_gate) is a common ion trap gate. Does Stim support it? I tried `MS 0 1` but it didn't work.

Comment: Received this question by email. Copying here for posterity.

Comment: There are many MS gates, you should be more specific.

Comment: @Mauricio Could you elaborate on that? Are you referring to the fact that it is normally parameterized by an angle (here I'm silently assuming you want the angle with maximum interaction strength), or something beyond that which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Do you mean a two qubit $\exp(-\frac\phi 2 i X\otimes X)$ or $\exp(-\frac\phi 2 i Y\otimes Y)$ or some other specific rotation? or more qubits? MS is more like a way of implementing these gates and not a unique version of it.

Comment: @Mauricio I meant $\exp(-i\phi/2 \cdot X\otimes X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Stim does support the Molmer–Sorensen gate, but it's not called `MS`. It's called [`SQRT_XX`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SQRT_XX).

The name comes from the fact that the Molmer–Sorensen gate is equal to $\sqrt{X \otimes X}$, the principle square root of applying a bit flip to both qubits. The Molmer–Sorensen gate phases the $-1$ eigenspace of $X \otimes X$ by $i$ instead of by $-1$, relative to the +1 eigenspace. Stim also has the inverse gate [`SQRT_XX_DAG`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SQRT_XX_DAG), as well as variants such as [`SQRT_ZZ`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SQRT_ZZ).